# Hi ! I'm trying to connect a local database from MySQL to PowerBI but I'm getting the same error every time

Tags: mysql, .net, powerbi

This is the error that I'm getting :

> Character set 'utf8mb3' is not supported by .Net Framework

I already checked in my database and it's configured as `utf8mb4`. I also had a problem about the versions of my connectors, so I fixed it returning to an early version of them, I have this versions.

mysql-connector-net-8.0.26
mysql-connector-odbc-8.1.0-winx64

Any advice is welcome! ty :D